# Manter o status do botão mesmo com refresh da página?

Tags: javascript

Observem a imagem gif!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O botão está com o status de Pausar Processamento, e só deve retorna com o status de Pausar Processamento somente depois que for clicado novamente, o que acontece é que o status muda quando é feito um refresh na página, o comportamento esperado era que ele mantivesse o status de Seguir Processamento mesmo sendo feito um refresh na página web, se somente mudar de status somente depois clicar no botão, como faço para corrigir esse problema?

Esse é meu botão;

```
<button id="btnAcao" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Pausar Processamento" onclick="pausar();">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i> Pausar Processamento
</button>
```

Esse é meu arquivo javascript na página;

```
function pausar(){
    var $btnAcao = $('#btnAcao');

    alert("status do botão  "  + $btnAcao.text().trim());

    if ($btnAcao.text().trim() === 'Pausar Processamento') {
        //$btnAcao.text('Iniciar Processamento');
        $btnAcao.html('').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></i> Seguir Processamento");
        $btnAcao.attr("title", "Seguir Processamento");
    } else {
        //$btnAcao.text('Pausar Processamento');
        $btnAcao.html('').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pause'></i> Pausar Processamento");
    $btnAcao.attr("title", "Pausar Processamento");
    }

    $.post('AdministracaoRemessa!pausar', function(retorno) {});
}
```

Comment: Você até consegue fazer isso armazenando localmente o status do botão, mas seria gambiarra e abrir brecha para problemas posteriores. A solução ideal é que você verifique no servidor o status deste "processamento" e exiba o botão conforme o resultado.  Basicamente, se o "processamento" está ativo, exibir o botão de pausar, se está pausado exibir o botão de seguir.

Comment: existe um método do javascript para isso? parece que tem o **on** e o **off** né?

Comment: Não, isso depende do seu backend. Você pode fazer isso em *server-side*, quando constrói a página HTML ou precisará fazer a requisição de forma assíncrona a partir do JavaScript.